# How to prove or disprove that such a hexagon exists?

Tags: geometry

How can we prove or disprove that there exists an equiangular hexagon with sides lengths of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and $6$, not necessarily in order? I am completely stumped. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the coordinate system described by Henning the alternatives for the direction of a side are the vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ and their negatives (these are all actually unit vectors). The sum vector
$$
a(1,0)+b(0,1)+c(-1,1)=(0,0)
$$
if and only if $b=-c=-a$. All the integers $a,b,c$ are actually difference of two distinct numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Therefore a solution that immediately stands out is
$$
a=1-4,\qquad b=5-2,\qquad c=3-6.
$$

---

One way of traversing the hexagon realizing this solution is the route:
$$
(0,0)\to(1,0)\to(1,5)\to(-2,8)\to(-6,8)\to(-6,6)\to(0,0)
$$
with respective side vectors $\vec{u}$, $5\vec{v}$, $3\vec{w}$, $-4\vec{u}$,
$-2\vec{v}$ and $-6\vec{w}$. Here $\vec{u}=(1,0)$ is the unit vector pointing in the direction of positive $x$-axis, $\vec{v}=(0,1)$ is the unit vector gotten by rotating $\vec{u}$ 60 degrees counterclockwise and $\vec{w}=(-1,1)$ is the unit vector gotten by rotating $\vec{v}$ 60 degrees counterclockwise.

Here's what this looks like:
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's easier than a brute-force search.

Comment: It would be slightly easier to visualize if you used $w=(-1,1)$ instead, though -- then the directions of the sides as we move around the hexagon are $\vec u,\vec v,\vec w,-\vec u,-\vec v,-\vec w$, and it is easier to read off the side lengths in order from the solution for $a,b,c$.

Comment: A good suggestion, Henning!

Comment: Another solution is that the differences of lengths of opposite sides are all equal to one unit. A sequence that works is then $1,4,5,2,3,6$.

Answer (score 3):

If you extend alternate pairs of sides of an equiangular hexagon you get an equilateral triangle, where the hexagon is obtained by chopping equilateral triangles from the corners of the triangle.

Let the sides which are chopped off corners be $a, c, e$ and the others be $b,d,f$ where the letters run clockwise.

Then, because the triangle is equilateral, we have $$a+b+c=c+d+e=e+f+a$$ as a necessary and sufficient condition.

So $a+b=d+e$, and we can choose $a=1$ by choosing which corners to chop off, whence $a+b\le 7$, so $d+e=2+3,2+4,3+4$ are the only possibilities. Likewise with $c+d=f+a$. So in some order $c+d+e=2+3+4=9$

So if $b=5$ we must have $f=6$ and if $b=6$ then $f=5$. Since we could run counterclockwise instead, we can choose $b=5$ and $f=6$.  This gives $$1+5+c=9 (=c+d+e)=e+6+1$$. Whence $e=2, c=3, d=4$ and this is essentially the only solution.

Comment: +1 Lovely proof :) .. an alternative could be to draw lines parallel to the alternate sides inside equiangular hexagon and argue that the these 3 lines meet each other to form an equilateral triangle of side length $1$ or $3$, concluding $e=2, c=3, d=4$ are the only solution .. :)

Comment: +1 Exactly what I would have done when I would got that equilateral triangle idea before. :)

Answer (score 2):

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: example]

Just testing a new method for drawing hexagons $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Since the hexagon is "equiangular" every interior angle is 120°. If we consider it in a skewed coordinate system where the axes make an angle of 60° (rather than the usual 90°), then all points in the hexagon will have *integer* coordinates.

Given a possible sequence of side lengths -- say, $3,5,4,2,6,1$ -- you can put one corner at $(0,0)$ and calculate the coordinates of the corners as you go clockwise around the hexagon. If you end up at $(0,0)$ after going all the way around, you've found a solution.

Up to cyclic rotations and mirrorings, there are $5!/2=60$ conceivable sequences of side lengths, which is few enough that you could do a brute-force search for solution with pencil and paper. But it's probably less tedious to program a computer search if you know a programming language.

Comment: 60 sequences! I had seen that aspect, and you think we can do it by hand! Is there any trick or so? [And it comes from a old contest problem book I have, so its unlikely that we would have much time.]

Comment: @Sawarnik: With a pad of graph paper it takes about 10 seconds to check one sequence. That's 10 minutes of work -- probably quicker than trying to be smart, if you've already spent so much time thinking that asking here is relevant.

Comment: With a pad of graph paper, so it would mean checking rough approximations and seeing which of them clear? 10 seconds is not fair though, doing it 60 times will make you tired and slow.

Comment: @Sawarnik: No rough approximation -- just draw the candidate figures one by one and see of they close up or not. The corners will always be lattice points, so there's no doubt whether you hit the starting point or not.

Comment: Why will it be lattice points? I think the angle which give that are 90 and 135 and not 120. Besides, I don't think we would have pad to work with in the contest, at the first place.

Comment: Hey, I think I hit upon an idea. If it an equiangular hexagon, it can be inscribed in an equilateral triangle, right? Will that help.